# Python having date as an parameter

Tags: python, oop

```
from datetime import datetime

class User:

    def __init__(self, username, mail, date_of_birth, gender, password):
        self.username = username
        self.mail = mail
        self.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
        self.gender = gender
        self.password = password

    def get_username(self):
        return self.username

    def get_mail(self):
        return self.mail

    def get_date_of_birth(self):
        return self.date_of_birth
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender

    def get_password(self):
        self.password

    def get_date(self):
        return self.date_of_birth



Matt = User("Matterson", "matt@gmail.com", "21.12.1999" ,"male", "Password987")
```

Someone told me to do this like this datetime.datetime.strptime not this datetime.strptime, why do i get an error?

```
error: self.date_of_birth = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y").date()
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: since your import is already importing the datetime module from the datetime package, you're really telling it to do datetime.datetime.datetime

Comment: fix it by changing the import to "import datetime" or change your code to "datetime.strptime..."

Comment: What's the difference between: from datetime import datetime and import datetime?

Comment: there is a class `datetime` in the module `datetime.py`; `datetime.datetime` refers to the class within the module by the same name: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/95f710c55714153f0c8cce48f8215bb3d866ac1d/Lib/datetime.py#L1563

Answer (score 0):

You have imported datetime as :

```
from datetime import datetime
```

This is does not work when you use `datetime.datetime` as you imported the type, not the module

change the import statement to :

```
import datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes python modules have a like-named function or class inside them. This makes the import a bit awkward. You can import the module and use the object as in

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime(2020,10,27)
```

But that's a bit wordy, so you could import `datetime` but only add the `datetime` variable to your namspace.

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime(2020, 10, 27)
```

The `datetime` implementers looked at the `strptime` function and decided that since it returns a `datetime` object, it should be implemented as a class method on the `datetime` class. So, with our two options you can

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
my_date = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

"datetime" and "datetime" are different things that can make this all confusing. I tend to

```
import datetime as dt
```

and luckily I haven't bumped into another class called "dt"